# How can I change the 12 word phrase in my trust wallet?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, private-key, trust

I created a ETH trust wallet on my phone for someone and he has now imported the trust wallet to his phone.  Is there any way to change the 12 word phrase or somehow give the sole control to the wallet to him?  He is concerned about security as the wallet still shows on my phone and I have the 12 word phrase.

Comment: Is there way to fully take out control from the wallet owner after acquiring phrase keys ? Can we add more security tags which restrict old owner's access ??

Answer (score 2):

Private keys are derived from the mnemonic phrase directly, so if you use a different mnemonic phrase (different words), you'll get different private keys, and thus addresses.

The best way to approach this is to generate a new mnemonic phrase and move (send) all funds from the old addresses to the new ones. They should generate the new phrase themselves, so only they have access to this phrase.

Comment: Unfortunately the current wallet is attached to a project using smart contracts, whereas wallet address cannot be changed from that project. Any other ideas would be grateful.

Comment: re-deploy the smart contract in question and never have static values within a smart contract without a secure update strategy in place.

Answer (score 0):

In ethereum Private/public key pair is derived using the mnemonic values, wallet address is derived from the public key value. Changing the mnemonic will result in a new wallet.